# Jquery slideshow not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the slideshow from http://www.hugoandcat.com/DualSlider/, I have added all the required css & javascript files, but still the slideshow does not work.
The url to my implementation is http://geddit.in/
What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be loading in jQuery twice on your page - first on line 28 and then later on line 64.

I'd remove the second appearence.

Comment: I'd remove the first instance - it's way older ;)

Comment: Well yes, agree, except the slideshow plugin is built with jquery 1.3.  Is jquery backwards compatible?

Comment: jQuery is *mostly* backwards-compatible - I believe there have been very few breaking changes (i.e. code-removal) since 1.3, mostly just additions. Certainly moving from 1.3 to 1.6 should be ok. Tbh, I'd remove the plguin as well!

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know this :)  When I check out the OP's page in Chrome it is saying there is no method called dualSlider() - even though the plugin is there.  I'm guessing everything is reset when you load jQuery in again?  Is that right?

Comment: yeah, the new `fn` object will replace the previous `fn` object containing the plugin's method

Comment: Thank you that got the slideshow working. But, when I remove the second appearance of the jquery, then the pin posts below the slideshow stop working, can something be done to make both the things working ?

Comment: Have you updated geddit.in with your new code?  Also do you know about how to use developer tools in IE, Firefox or Chrome to detect javascript errors like these?

Comment: I couldn't find where is the second appearance of the jquery included, so I just renamed the .js file to something else. 
Sorry, but I don't know how to use firebug to detect these errors. Maybe, you can provide me with a link to the tutorial, so that the next time I can solve this myself.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I just used jquery 1.6.0 & it worked.

Comment: Great stuff.  If you just download Google Chrome, you'll find lots of useful tools for developers including a really useful javascript console where you can test out your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

```
Please remove 

<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/ae1550c2/jquery.min.js"></script>

from your code. You have used <script type="text/javascript" src="/css/slideshow/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"> in top of your page with dualSlider js.
```